# handle an arrray posted with $.ajax (jquery) to a webservice

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, web-services

I'm trying to post data to a webservice (asp.net 3.5), like below (two variants, one commented):

```
var array = [3, 2, 5, 1, 7];
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(array);
//var jsonString = '{ "firstName": "John", "lastName": "Smith", "age": 25, "address": { "streetAddress": "21 2nd Street", "city": "New York", "state": "NY", "postalCode": "10021" }, "phoneNumber": [ { "type": "home", "number": "212 555-1234" }, { "type": "fax", "number": "646 555-4567" } ] }'

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "WebService2.asmx/AddRoute",
    data: jsonString,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    processData: "false",
    error: function(msg) {
        alert('error' + msg.toString);
    }
});
```

So I need a matching webmethod to recieve it. Something like this:

```
[WebMethod]
public string AddRoute(/* xxx */)
{
    //handle data
}
```

Could someone please elaborate on how I can fetch the data, where I've typed "xxx"?
I would have thought "int[] array" would do the trick, but it's not working.
Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: You could cheat, declare it as `object`, break in the method with a debugger and see what type it actually is.

Comment: Also, based on the commented out bit of JavaScript, this may be useful http://encosia.com/2009/04/07/using-complex-types-to-make-calling-services-less-complex/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with ASP.NET but, there should be some way for you to obtain request parameters that are being passed using `jQuery.ajax()`.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "WebService2.asmx/AddRoute",
    **data: {'some_data': jsonString},**
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    processData: "false",
    error: function(msg) {
        alert('error' + msg.toString);
    }
});
```

The request parameter would be some_data.  From your controller, you can retrieve the request parameter without it being passed as an argument to your function.

I apologize for it being vague as I come from a Python/Pylons background.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of an .asmx web service, you should just expose an asp.net mvc action method. This post by Phil Haack shows just how easy it is to accept strongly typed json data (including arrays):
http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/15/sending-json-to-an-asp-net-mvc-action-method-argument.aspx

Comment: R0MANARMY, and Joel, thank you very much for your replies!
I got it working the way it is described on 'encosia' with a web service. So I'm sticking to that for now. However I will look into mvc as well later on. Not that I plan to recieve any errors :D but if I did they would obviously be easier to handle with mvc.

Again, thank's for taking time. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the following code:
You could have int[] instead of string[] as well

---

`[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "ServiceName", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
            Method = "POST")]

        public string ServiceName(string[] ids)`

Answer (score 0):

Declare your service class as this

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class WFSrvc
{
    // To use HTTP GET, add [WebGet] attribute. (Default ResponseFormat is WebMessageFormat.Json)
    // To create an operation that returns XML,
    //     add [WebGet(ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Xml)],
    //     and include the following line in the operation body:
    //         WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "text/xml";
    [OperationContract]
    public void DoWork()
    {
        // Add your operation implementation here
        return;
    }

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
    public string HelloWorld()
    {
        return "Hello World";

    }
```

}

instead of helloworld you can put your own function

Answer (score 0):

your ajax post needs to be something like this

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'WebService2.asmx/AddRoute',
    data: '{arr:'+ JSON.stringify(array)+'}',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (msg) {
         console.log(msg.d);
         }
});
```

and your webmethod

```
[WebMethod]
public string AddRoute(int[] arr) //parameter name and the name in data:{} should be same
{
    //handle data
}
```